# getting service instance in controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a service instance but am getting an error. I am getting the exception that Calculator.random() is not a function. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Calculator',function(){
        var random = {};
        random.number = function (){
            return Math.random();
        };
        return random;
    });

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope','Calculator', function ($scope,Calculator) {

        $scope.random = Calculator.random();

    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
angular
.module('app').controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, Calculator) {
$scope.random=Calculator.number();//in your factory number holds the random function.
}
```

IN your case its breaking 
reason: *Calculator.random();* is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Like Cyril said, you define an object with a local name random in the calculator factory definition.  You then return that object but that object has a property called number that points to a function not a property called random.

```js
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .factory('Calculator',function(){
        var random = {};
        random.number = function (){
            return Math.random();
        };
        return random;
    });

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope','Calculator', function ($scope,Calculator) {

        $scope.random = Calculator.number();

    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="homeCtrl">{{random}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .factory('Calculator', function () {
        return function () {
            return Math.random();
        }
    });`
```